# My code is not working? (function prototype, function call and function definition)

Tags: c

This is C program. The code cannot read after asking user time in and out.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>//0.25m

float calculateCharges(int, int, int, int);//0.5m
void display(float);//0.5m

int main()//0.25m
{
    int timeln_H, timeln_M, timeOut_H, timeOut_M;
    float charge;//1m
    
    printf("Time in (HH) :");
    scanf("%d", &timeln_H);//0.5m
    
    printf("Time in (MM) :");
    scanf("%d", &timeln_M);//0.5m
    
    printf("Time out (HH) :");
    scanf("%d", timeOut_H);//0.5m
    
    printf("Time out (MM) :");
    scanf("%d", timeOut_M);//0.5m
    
    charge = calculateCharges(timeln_H, timeln_M, timeOut_H, timeOut_M);//0.5m
    printf("\nChargr", charge);
    
    display(charge);//0.5m
    
    return 0;
}

float calculateCharges(int tlh, int tlm, int tOh, int tOm)//0.5m
{
    float charge;
    int total_min1, total_min2, total, extramin;//1m
    
    total_min1 = tlh * 60 + tlm;//0.5m
    total_min2 = tOh * 60 + tOm;//0.5m
    
    total = total_min2 - total_min1;//0.5m
    
    //printf("%d",total);
    printf("You have parked for %d hours(s) and minute(s)\n", total / 60, total % 60);//0.25m
    
    if (total <= 180)
        charge = 1.50;//0.5m
    else
    {
        if (total % 60 == 0)//0.5m
            charge = 1.50 + (total / 60 - 3) * 1.00;//0.5m
        else
            charge = 1.50 + (total / 60 - 3 + 1) * 1.00;//0.5m
    }    
    return charge;//0.5m
}

void display(float charge)//0.5m
{
    printf("Total charge = RM%.2f\n", charge);//0.25m
}
```

Comment: Please turn on your compiler warnings. The `scanf` calls for the time out require a pointer to `int`, so make one with the address-of operator `&` like you did with scanning the time in.

Comment: What are these comments for: `//0.5m`...

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the address of the destination `int` to `scanf()` to parse a decimal integer with `%d`: the statements `scanf("%d", timeOut_H);` and `scanf("%d", timeOut_M);` should read:

```
printf("Time out (HH): ");
scanf("%d", &timeOut_H);//0.5m

printf("Time out (MM): ");
scanf("%d", &timeOut_M);//0.5m
```

There is also a missing `%d` in `printf("You have parked for %d hours(s) and minute(s)\n", total / 60, total % 60);`